# Intellij Idea + Windows : launch different browsers by url rule?

Tags: intellij-idea, browser

Being a web developer, I use a few browser instances. I have one for the web apps I develop, one for my documentation tools and another for anything else (social sites, email, etc).

On Windows, I'd like Intellij Idea to launch different browser instances based on the URL:

- all with `localhost` = development browser
- all with `jetbrains` or `stackoverflow` = documentation browser
- anything else = personal browser.

Can that be done ?  On Mac I used to have an app which achieved just this, called `Choosy`. It would display a popup of browser choices when desired (regex rule based), but I have not found a similar Windows alternative. A system-wide one would be nice, but isn't there at least a way to achieve this in Intellij ?

Comment: Request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Anyone know of an IJ plugin then for this?

Comment: [Feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188182) posted :-)

Answer (score 0):

I [found and tried a few alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/choosy/?platform=windows) to achieve this (on Mac I've used [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/)  which was great btw).

The best I've found so far is [Browser Selector](https://github.com/DanTup/BrowserSelector), free & open-source. It does a decent job at catching system-wide links, outside of a browser. Then it's possible to define some regex rules-based routing by URLs to various browsers with command-line switches (for profile selection, etc).

So it fits *most* of my needs. I'm suprised that not many more options exist, so please contribute if you do know of other choices on Windows.